Attempting to Add a Row in MySQL via Java Spring Boot in Eclipse
I'm attempting to add a row to a MySQL local database via Java Spring Boot in Eclipse. I'm able to get a 200 code returned, however I've since learned that the 200 code doesn't really mean much. I have a Controller endpoint that looks like this:
@PostMapping("/addFood")
public ResponseEntity<String> addFood(@RequestBody FoodDto foodDto){
    try {
        FoodDto savedFoodObject = dietService.addFood(foodDto);
        if(savedFoodObject != null && savedFoodObject.getName() != null) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Update successful");
        }
        else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Update failed for unknown reasons.");
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
    }
}

A service method that looks like this:
public FoodDto addFood(FoodDto foodDto) {
    Food foodModel = FoodMapper.INSTANCE.toFood(foodDto);
    Food food = foodRepository.save(foodModel);
    return FoodMapper.INSTANCE.toFoodDto(food);
}

foodRepository is an object of type interface that extends JPARepository. The model class is called "Food" and the DTO class is called "FoodDto". I can see that "food" in the second line of the service class isn't null, and has all of the values that are expected that were passed from the request on PostMan. The mappers do what they're supposed to do, and "Update successful" is returned.
I've played around with application.properties and compose.yaml, have looked at every single character to make sure they're correct, but I cannot see any rows in MySQL WorkBench. I know I'm looking at the right database, and can see that my project has created the "food" table successfully via the Food model class that is marked as an "entity". My compose.yaml looks like this:
services:
  mysql:
    image: 'mysql:latest'
    environment:
      - 'MYSQL_DATABASE=dietplan_database'
      - 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=PASSWORD' (I've hardcoded my actual password here as this is my computer, but have changed it to "PASSWORD" for posting sake.)
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'

While application.properties looks like this:
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.application.name=dietPlanFullStackApplication
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dietplan_database
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=PASSWORD (Same thing with this password)
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

I'm expecting that the database should have a row that corresponds to what I've included in the body of the HTML request, but unfortunately the database has 0 rows.
Food model class:
package com.dietPlan.models;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Food {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    
    private String name;
    private Integer calories;
    private Integer protein;
    private Integer carbs;
    private Integer sugar;
    private Integer fat;
    
    @Column(name = "saturated_fat")
    private Integer saturatedFat;
    
    private Integer sodium;
    private Integer potassium;
    private Boolean has_multiplier;
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public Integer getCalories() {
        return calories;
    }

    public void setCalories(Integer calories) {
        this.calories = calories;
    }

    public Integer getProtein() {
        return protein;
    }

    public void setProtein(Integer protein) {
        this.protein = protein;
    }

    public Integer getCarbs() {
        return carbs;
    }

    public void setCarbs(Integer carbs) {
        this.carbs = carbs;
    }

    public Integer getSugar() {
        return sugar;
    }

    public void setSugar(Integer sugar) {
        this.sugar = sugar;
    }

    public Integer getFat() {
        return fat;
    }

    public void setFat(Integer fat) {
        this.fat = fat;
    }

    public Integer getSaturatedFat() {
        return saturatedFat;
    }

    public void setSaturatedFat(Integer saturatedFat) {
        this.saturatedFat = saturatedFat;
    }

    public Integer getSodium() {
        return sodium;
    }

    public void setSodium(Integer sodium) {
        this.sodium = sodium;
    }

    public Integer getPotassium() {
        return potassium;
    }

    public void setPotassium(Integer potassium) {
        this.potassium = potassium;
    }
    
    public Boolean getHasMultiplier() {
        return has_multiplier;
    }
    
    public void setHasMultiplier(Boolean has_multiplier) {
        this.has_multiplier = has_multiplier;
    }
}


In the absence of an error message, it is a bit difficult to tell what's going wrong. Since you are using orm to manipulate data, the problem is with your use of orm, not directly with mysql.

This is my use of the "@" features on Java Spring Boot, is that correct?

I have a feeling that this is one more issue with imports in the Entity. javax vs jakarta. Can you please post your full entity (FoodDto) with import statements please?

Actually Food not FoodDto

The Food model class has been added to the post

Something I've noticed is that Hibernate is assigning values to the primary key "id" variable that is a generated value, and it is currently on value = 202. Wouldn't that mean there's 202 rows in the database? I'm wondering if I'm just looking at the wrong database in MySQL WorkBench...

The MySQL Workbench instance existed on port 3306, however, the Spring application was targeting a database on 3307, as my compose.yaml was targeting ports “3307:3306”.
I’ve switched MySQL Workbench over to port 3307, and everything is working as expected.

Please Check if your Metadata Mapping is correct and same as given in the table.
You have given
@Entity public class Food
which means your table name has to be Food only, if it's different then @Table is needed, same for each of the columns. Apart from that I don`t see any other issues here. You can turn on the debug and trace logs to check what's happening behind the scenes.
